# Downloading and ingesting a file from a browser automated process

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

I have a script that uses RSelenium to automate the download of an Excel file. What I'm trying to accomplish is this: Assume this is automated and running daily on a server. How do I download it and ingest it back into R?

```
library(rvest) 
library(RSelenium)

remDr <- remoteDriver(port=4444L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("http://abc.xyz.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fOrdersAndDelivery%2fOrderStatus.aspx")
username <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "ctl00$MainContent$Login1$UserName")
username$sendKeysToElement(list("xxx"))

password <- remDr$findElement(using = "name", value = "ctl00$MainContent$Login1$Password")
password$sendKeysToElement(list("xxx"))

login <- remDr$findElement(using = "name",value = "ctl00$MainContent$Login1$LoginButton")
login$clickElement()

format_status <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//*/option[@value = 'Excel']")
format_status$clickElement()

submit <- remDr$findElement(using = "id",value = "SubmitButton")
submit$clickElement()
```

That final `submit$clickElement()` is a button that looks like this:

[image]

It then begins to process before this pops up:

[image]

At the sametime, a new file appears in my "Downloads" folder that looks as such: `q5vu64p4.xlsx.part`

I do not know why it downloads as `xlsx.part`, much less know what the `.part` means. While I can open the file through Excel perfectly fine, it would be difficult to automate because the name of that file is different each time. One time it was `mkTjuSd2.xlsx.part` and another time it was `kZ8+dKF0.xlsx` so no consistency.

How can I correctly ingest the file in an automated manner?

Comment: does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a workaround, but you could identify the name of the file by checking the directory for the files that was added in the last x seconds. By doing so you can identify the name of the file.

```
fileNames <- list.files()
index <- which(Sys.time() - file.info(fileNames)$mtime < 1)
fileNames[index]
```

Example:

```
write.csv(1, file = "test2.csv")
fileNames <- list.files()
index <- which(Sys.time() - file.info(fileNames)$mtime < 1)
fileNames[index]
```